# Marks calculator for average

Tags: python, arrays, sum

I have used the sum function for the array.I need to use that so that if the list gets bigger, the total is still right. But I keep getting error.
This is the code I have:

```py
print("please enter your 5 marks below")



#read 5 inputs

mark1 = input("enter mark 1: ")

mark2 = input("enter mark 2: ")

mark3 = input("enter mark 3: ")

mark4 = input("enter mark 4: ")

mark5 = input("enter mark 5: ")

#create array/list with five marks

marksList = [mark1, mark2, mark3, mark4, mark5]

#print the array/list

print(marksList)

#calculate the sum and average

sumOfMarks = sum(marksList)

averageOfMarks = sum(marks_ist)/5

#display results

print("The sum of your marks is: "+str(sumOfMarks))

print("The average of your marks is: "+str(averageOfMarks))
```

Comment: please post the error that you are getting

Answer (score 1):

Thats because you get the input as a string and not int.

```
mark1 = int(input("enter mark 1: "))
```